# Display content of page template (get_page)

Tags: loop, content, pages

My problem is that I displayed content of 3 pages on index.php by using get_page(). The problem is that each of those pages have own page template

```
/*
Template Name: another page template
*/
```

which contains the loop with 3 posts in category.

This way I can see only content of page typed in WP editor but no trace of queried posts on pages.

How to display three posts from page template on index.php?

For displaying pages on index.php I'm using:

```
<?php
 $id = 1;
 $post = get_page($id);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
 echo $content;
?>
```

and pages have own template with the_loop:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'name', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ));
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what you are doing, particularly this part, "and each of those pages have page template which contains the loop with 3 posts in category..." What page templates are you talking about? You can only really have one per page load. Are you trying to print 3 posts after the first loop, as your code seems to be trying to do, or 9 as your description implies?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing the *database object* that is a post/page, and the *rendered output* that is a post/page. The data contained in the `wp_posts` and `wp_post_meta` tables define the post *object*. A *template file* defines the *rendered output* when a given *database object* is queried.

There are three types of queries: the *default, main* query for a given context, *secondary* queries defined by core (such as the Nav Menu), and *custom* queries, that are defined elsewhere (either by the Theme or by a Plugin).

The *default, main* query for a given context is never affected by custom queries, even though it can be modified, either by filtering `pre_get_posts` or by bludgeoning it with `query_posts()`.

What happens when you call `get_page()` is that WordPress queries the post *object* associated with a given ID, not the *template file* that would be used to render that object in its normal context.

Long story, short: if you want to run in some other context the same custom queries in each of your three custom page templates, you'll need to execute the same code as you use on those three custom page templates.

(Also: please say you've not modified your Theme's `index.php` file for this purpose? By doing so, you'll completely break the template hierarchy for your Theme.)

The cleanest solution would be to split out the custom query code into *template-part* files, one for each custom page template; perhaps:

- `loop-three-latest-category-x.php`
- `loop-three-latest-category-y.php`
- `loop-three-latest-category-z.php`

So, one of your custom page templates will look like so:

```
/**
 * Template Name: another page template
 * 
 * Category X custom page template
 * 
 * Used to display the three latest posts in 
 * category x.
 */

get_header();

get_template_part( 'loop-three-latest-category-x' );

get_footer();
```

Then, to output *all three* custom queries on the **site front page**, create a template file called **`front-page.php`**, and call all three template-part files from above:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front-page template
 * 
 * Used to render the site front page
 */

get_header();

get_template_part( 'loop-three-latest-category-x' );
get_template_part( 'loop-three-latest-category-y' );
get_template_part( 'loop-three-latest-category-z' );

get_footer();
```

Comment: Thank You Chip for deatiled answer and a solution! I'll definitely try Your way to solve my problem! :)